# backbone.js collection where() function

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, where-clause

I'm reading a book on rapid prototyping in JS. There is this line of code:

```
var appleModel = this.collection.where({name: appleName})[0];
```

I know `where()` returns matching models in the collection.   But what does the `[0]` at the end do?

Answer (score 8):

Backbone's `.where()` function returns an array of models. The `[0]` at the end simply takes the first model returned by `.where()`.

Comment: Thanks!   Makes more sense now.   If I were to omit the index [0] and there were multiple matches to appleName, I assume appleModel is assigned the first matching object?

Comment: If you were to omit the part at the end then your variable would be more appropriately called `appleModels` as it would be assigned the array returned from `.where()`.

Answer (score 4):

Backbone has its own method when it comes to searching for first result. `collection.findWhere(attributes)`

http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-findWhere

Answer (score 1):

From my python experience this selects the first element of an array. Obviously where() returns a list (array).